# How to avoid storing duplicate results

Tags: scrapy

I store scraped content within a csv file.
Each row contains a unique ID and description of an item.

My ID is coming from the website where I **scrape** the content and not generated on the scraper side.

I use Scrapy's feedExporter to generate the csv file

When I **scrape** again my website, I would like my script to check if unique ID is already stored within the csv file, if it's not I would add the new row, if it is I will just move on to the next item.

As I assume this is a classic thing to do with a scraping framework I believe there must be a smart way to do it with Scrapy however I can't find anything on this topic within the Scrapy's documentation

Should I simply open the csv file, go through each item and if iterator's value not present add a new row or skip if it is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent duplicates on Scrapy fetching depending on an existing JSON list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225781/how-to-prevent-duplicates-on-scrapy-fetching-depending-on-an-existing-json-list)

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter

Comment: Apart from the example that @Gallaecio linked, if you use distributed system like Scrapy Cluster, you might want to use something like Redis to hold the set of seen IDs.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to create an empty HashMap.  Then on the first scan, put your items in the HashMap.  HashMaps do not hold duplicate values.  So in light of this on your second scan, look up the key, and if the key exists, onto the next.  If it doesn't exist, add it.